# Xamarin Forms Prism MVVM nested TabbedPage problem

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, prism, prism-7

I am using Xamarin Forms with Prism MVVM framework.

I have a problem when doing nested TabbedPage.

For example I have TabbedPage1.

Then I add TabbedPage2 and Page99 as the children of TabbedPage1.

Then I add Page1 and Page2 as the children of TabbedPage2.

But the result is Page1 and Page2 become blank Page and the title of Page1 and 
Page2 become the title of TabbedPage2

I'm using Xamarin 3.1.0.697729 and Prism 7.0.0.396

This is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KabjS.jpg)

This is the reproduction [full project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xcnXwVWM1LlPhIg92nOAe8V4YRQz3Yad) or [github](https://github.com/rredoh/Prism-Nested-TabbedPage-Problem)
. I made an example the difference of using mvvm and not.

This is some source code

TabbedPage1.xaml

```
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="AssetKita.Views.TabbedPage1"
        Title="{Binding Title}"
        xmlns:Existing_Page="clr-namespace:AssetKita.Views">

    <ContentPage Title="Tab 1" />
    <ContentPage Title="Tab 2" />
    <ContentPage Title="Tab 3" />
    <Existing_Page:TabbedPage2/>
    <ContentPage Title="Tab 5" />
</TabbedPage>
```

TabbedPage1.xaml.cs

```
namespace AssetKita.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class TabbedPage1 : Xamarin.Forms.TabbedPage
    {
        public TabbedPage1 ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetToolbarPlacement(Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific.ToolbarPlacement.Bottom);
            On<Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.Android>().SetBarSelectedItemColor((Color)App.Current.Resources["PrimaryGreenColor"]);
        }
    }
}
```

TabbedPage2.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="AssetKita.Views.TabbedPage2"
        xmlns:Existing_Page="clr-namespace:AssetKita.Views"
        Title="{Binding Title}">
    <Existing_Page:Page1/>
    <Existing_Page:Page2/>
</TabbedPage>
```

Page1.xaml and Page2.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="AssetKita.Views.ItemList_Invest_Page"
         Title="{Binding Title}">

<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding PostItems, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SeparatorVisibility="None"
          CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
          HasUnevenRows="True"
          x:Name="listview_item">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Frame Padding="0" Margin="10">
                    <Frame.HasShadow>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="x:Boolean" iOS="True" Android="True">
                        </OnPlatform>
                    </Frame.HasShadow>
                    <Frame.BorderColor>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color" iOS="Transparent" Android="Default"/>
                    </Frame.BorderColor>
                    <Frame.BackgroundColor>
                        <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color" iOS="Transparent" Android="Default"/>
                    </Frame.BackgroundColor>
                    <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                          VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                          Padding="10"
                          RowSpacing="5"
                          ColumnSpacing="5">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Image Grid.Column="0"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Grid.RowSpan="5"
                               Margin="0,0,10,0"
                               Source="{Binding IMAGE_LINK}"
                               Aspect="AspectFill"/>

                        <Label Text="{Binding NAME}"
                               FontSize="Medium"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="0"
                               Grid.ColumnSpan="4"/>

                        <Label Text="Kategori"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <Label Text="Bunga"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="2"/>
                        <Label Text="Durasi"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="3"/>

                        <Label Text=":"
                               Grid.Column="2"
                               Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <Label Text=":"
                               Grid.Column="2"
                               Grid.Row="2"/>
                        <Label Text=":"
                               Grid.Column="2"
                               Grid.Row="3"/>

                        <Label Text="{Binding CATEGORY}"
                               Grid.Column="3"
                               Grid.Row="1"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding ASKING_INTEREST_RATE}"
                               Grid.Column="3"
                               Grid.Row="2"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding DURATION}"
                               Grid.Column="3"
                               Grid.Row="3"/>
                        <Label x:Name="label_price"
                               FontSize="Medium"
                               TextColor="#FF6F00"
                               Grid.Column="1"
                               Grid.Row="4"
                               Grid.ColumnSpan="4"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Page1ViewModel.cs and Page2ViewModel.cs

```
namespace AssetKita.ViewModels
{
    class Page1ViewModel : ViewModelChild
    {
        private List<PostItem> postItems = new List<PostItem>()
        {
            new PostItem
            {
                NAME = "Emas 24 Karat",
                    ASKING_INTEREST_RATE = "2%",
                    ASKING_PRICE = "1.000.000",
                    CATEGORY = "Emas",
                    DESCRIPTION = "Berat 3 gram",
                    DURATION = "30 hari",
                    IMAGE_LINK = "https://fm.cnbc.com/applications/cnbc.com/resources/img/editorial/2017/10/02/104748034-GettyImages-90075023.530x298.jpg?v=1506995840"
            },
            new PostItem
                {
                    NAME = "Redmi Note 5",
                    ASKING_INTEREST_RATE = "2%",
                    ASKING_PRICE = "2.000.000",
                    CATEGORY = "Smartphone",
                    DESCRIPTION = "Mulus Like New",
                    DURATION = "30 hari",
                    IMAGE_LINK = "http://st1.bgr.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/02/Xiaomi-Redmi-Note-5-Front.jpg"
                },
                new PostItem
                {
                    NAME = "MacBook Pro 15 inch 2018",
                    ASKING_INTEREST_RATE = "2%",
                    ASKING_PRICE = "20.000.000",
                    CATEGORY = "Elektronik",
                    DESCRIPTION = "Mulus Like New",
                    DURATION = "30 hari",
                    IMAGE_LINK = "https://www.insightmac.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/26826-38847-2018-MacBook-Pro-15-inch-l.jpg"
                },
        };
        public List<PostItem> PostItems
        {
            get { return postItems; }
            set { SetProperty(ref postItems, value); }
        }

        public ItemList_Invest_ViewModel(INavigationService navigationService,
            IPageDialogService pageDialog)
        {
            Title = "INVEST";
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModelChild.cs

```
namespace AssetKita.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModelChild : ViewModelBase, IActiveAware
    {
        private string _message;
        public string Message
        {
            get { return _message; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _message, value); }
        }

        private bool _isActive;
        public bool IsActive
        {
            get { return _isActive; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _isActive, value, () => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{Title} IsActive Changed: {value}")); }
        }

        public event EventHandler IsActiveChanged;

        public ViewModelChild()
        {
            IsActiveChanged += (sender, e) => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{Title} IsActive: {IsActive}");
        }

        public override void OnNavigatingTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{Title} is executing OnNavigatingTo");
            var message = parameters.GetValue<string>("message");
            Message = $"{Title} Initialized by OnNavigatingTo: {message}";
        }

        public override void Destroy()
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"{Title} is being Destroyed!");
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModelBase.cs

```
namespace AssetKita.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModelBase : BindableBase, INavigationAware, IDestructible
    {
        protected INavigationService NavigationService { get; private set; }

        private string _title;
        public string Title
        {
            get { return _title; }
            set { SetProperty(ref _title, value); }
        }


        public virtual void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationParameters parameters)
        {

        }

        public virtual void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
        {

        }

        public virtual void OnNavigatingTo(NavigationParameters parameters)
        {

        }

        public virtual void Destroy()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

PostItem.cs

```
    namespace AssetKita.Models
    {
        class PostItem
        {
            public string IMAGE_LINK { get; set; }
            public string NAME { get; set; }
            public string WEIGHT { get; set; }
            public string CATEGORY { get; set; }
            public string ASKING_PRICE { get; set; }
            public string ASKING_INTEREST_RATE { get; set; }
            public string DURATION { get; set; }
            public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }

            public Owner owner { get; set; }
            public string OWNER_LOCATION
            {
                get { return owner.LOCATION; }
                set { owner.LOCATION = value; }
            }
        }
    }
```

Owner.cs

```
namespace AssetKita.Models
{
    class PostItem
    {
        public string IMAGE_LINK { get; set; }
        public string NAME { get; set; }
        public string WEIGHT { get; set; }
        public string CATEGORY { get; set; }
        public string ASKING_PRICE { get; set; }
        public string ASKING_INTEREST_RATE { get; set; }
        public string DURATION { get; set; }
        public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }

        public Owner owner { get; set; }
        public string OWNER_LOCATION
        {
            get { return owner.LOCATION; }
            set { owner.LOCATION = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

App.xaml.cs

```
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace AssetKita
{
    public partial class App : PrismApplication
    {
        public App() : this(null) { }

        public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer) : base(initializer) { }

        protected override async void OnInitialized()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("NavigationPage/TabbedPage1");
        }

        protected override void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<NavigationPage>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<TabbedPage1>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<TabbedPage2>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Page1>();
            containerRegistry.RegisterForNavigation<Page2>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow has option to insert image in you question and also please don't upload your entire project, paste here all relevant code/classes etc. ... btw welcome to Stackoverflow :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion and ther warm welcome @AlmirVuk.. Just edited.. :)